# Multiple bytes of data not being read from PIC18F46K80

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart, microchip, terminal

I am trying to receive multiple bytes of data from the hyper terminal to PIC18F46K80.

This is my source code

```
uint8_t uart_recv_uchar() {
   while(!(PIR1bits.RC1IF))
   {
       //wait till the data is received
       ;
   }
   return RCREG;
}


uint8_t uart_get_value() {
    uint8_t byte[5];
    byte[0] = uart_recv_uchar();
    byte[1] = uart_recv_uchar(); 
    byte[2] = uart_recv_uchar();
    byte[3] = uart_recv_uchar(); 
    byte[4] = '\0';
    return (uint8_t) strtol(byte, NULL, 16);
}
```

When I type the data that I intend to send more than one byte of data by typing 0x1234 on the terminal the microcontroller reads only the first byte of data 0x12 and then waits for the next byte at the statement byte[2]=uart_recv_uchar().

What should I do to read multiple bytes of data after typing them at once from the terminal?

Comment: Change the code. This is not an EE question.

Comment: Check for overrun & framing errors. You say it stops at 'byte[2]=...' but that's the 3rd byte, not the second. So have you actually received 2 bytes?

Comment: Yes it stops at the third byte, I've also checked for overrun and framing errors by using this code:- if (RCSTA1bits.OERR) {
        /* overrun error, reset CREN */
        RCSTA1bits.CREN = 0;
        RCSTA1bits.CREN = 1;
    }

    while (!PIR1bits.RC1IF);
    return RCREG1;
} But it still does not work

Comment: "0x1234" is six characters - your program only reads the first four.

Comment: Do you use hyperterminal in binary mode? then "0x1234" will only send two bytes - 0x12 and 0x34.

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to use the function defined in PIC18 peripheral library for UART.

```
char RxBuffer[5];
OpenUART2( UART_EN | UART_NO_PAR_8BIT | UART_1STOPBIT, UART_RX_ENABLE | UART_TX_ENABLE, (pbFreq/16/BAUDRATE)-1);
while(1)
{
    if((U2STAbits.URXDA)!=0)
    {
        getsUART2(5,RxBuffer , 123);
        U2STAbits.URXDA = 0;
        U2STAbits.OERR = 0; 
    }
    putsUART2(RxBuffer);
 }
```